# DFSR deleted whole folder

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-r

I had a folder shared on my windows network. I wanted that folder to by replicated with DFSR, so I created a target folder in a DFS namespace and a replication group with it. One of the targets was the original share with files in it, and I wanted those files to be replicated. The other targets were new empty folders.

The folder in the DFS namespace was empty (makes sense, I just created it, and it probably haven't replicated yet). However, in a few minutes, the original folder was empty too. Seems windows decided, that the "newer" empty fodlders were "newer", therefore replicated that. But now the files are gone and even testdisk can't find them. They aren't in `DfsrPrivate` or anywhere else.

Is it possible, and if so how, to recover them?

Comment: How to recover them? From your backup.

Answer (score 1):

Found out, that DFSR hides the preexisting files in `System volume information`, and the maps to them in some XML in `DFSR private`. They can be recovered with `Get-DfsrPreservedFiles` and `Restore-DfsrPreservedFiles`.